# Pygame in Ubuntu Minmal

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, xorg

I am making a GUI using Pygame in Ubuntu Minimal 18.04, i have fully programmed it and it run almost perfectly. But, despite installing xorg, pygame cannot find any display output capable of displaying the GUI (Python without a GUI works fine). I have tried running a both at once (But technically you can't) with the command: 'python3 'My script name' && startx', which runs both successfully, but doesn't run at the same exact time. xorg quits before python starts, and in reverse, python gives it's error before it starts xorg.

Thanks in advance, i appreciate it!

The exact error is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn1uT.png)

The code, which is probably irrelivant is (This is a version for my Windows 10 PC, not the Ubuntu Minimal version, it just has the directorys changes to /Application/ not X:\ )

```
import pygame as p3

#unimportant variables here, the code is 497 line long

p3.init()
p3.display.set_caption("P3tray.OS")
screen = p3.display.set_mode((1000,600), p3.FULLSCREEN)
screen.fill((255,255,255))
logo = p3.image.load("X:\\images\\logo.ico").convert()
general_font = p3.font.Font("X:\\images\\ascii\\font.ttf", 20)
system_font = p3.font.Font("X:\\images\\ascii\\font.ttf", 20)
notepad_font = p3.font.Font("X:\\images\\ascii\\font.ttf", 20)
p3.display.set_icon(logo)
```

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I added my code, and also read the first link, which i haven't read yet i think. I have read the others.

Comment: "pygame cannot find..." note that this is an interpretation. Please first and foremost describe observable facts! In particular, quote the error message that the MCVE emits verbatim. Also, concerning your code, it isn't helpful if you complain about problems with Xorg under Ubuntu and then provide MS Windows paths. Also, on pretty much any system, the code would fail trying to load `logo.ico` because that only exists on your system. Your supposed MCVE is thus not complete and also not verifiable. BTW: If it doesn't even reach that line, then it isn't minimal and could be reduced instead.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have added an image of the error in the question for you. Python/Pygame can find all of the files perfectly fine, as they are all on the computer. I sent everything of my windows 10 PC via my network, copied and pasted them to directory using the terminal, edited the original python script to work on linux, which was a case of changing the directory locations of items, such as logo.ico. Python checks if it can find these directories before running the program. The problem is what you can see in the image i added, Pygame cannot find anywhere to display my GUI. Hope this helps!

Comment: There's still a long way to go. Images of text are a bad idea, because they can't be searched easily, e.g. if you just throw the error message in a websearch to find if anyone else stumbled across the problem. Do that now. Further, that error refers to line 34, but your example code does not have a line 34. That means that the example is not the code causing the error. Also, it is the line `screen = ...`, so everything after that is exactly what I was hinting at with my last sentence: Superfluous.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt   The error is referring to that line, the line is pygame creating the GUI, and as i have said, it cannot find anywhere to put it, and also as i have said, the problem isn't exactly python related to some extent, the code works fine on OS's like Windows and Manjaro, but cant run in Ubuntu Minimal because it cannot find a display output. Xorg is not automatically installed with ubuntu minimal as its just a command line. I'm not too sure what else there is to say about the issue, i don't think you get it either, but if you do, or anyone else does, that would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Driver related problem, Ubuntu Minimal doesn't have the required drivers to run the Pygame GUI, so in order to run the GUI, you must first install the required drivers for your device. I do not know how it install the drivers on Ubuntu Minimal, so in the mean time i would settle for another distro.